# What's the proper way to implement an Android widget with dynamically drawn content?

Tags: android, android-widget

For my first and most awesomest Android project, I want to create a home screen widget which displays one of those [Arc Clocks](http://www.softpedia.com/progScreenshots/An-Arc-Clock-Screenshot-79251.html) that all the kids are raving about these days.

Based on the limitations of [RemoteViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html), it looks to me that the appropriate way to get it actually drawn on the screen is to use an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) in the actual layout, then when it is updating, create a [ShapeDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html) or two and draw them onto a newly created [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).  Then, set that Bitmap as the source of the ImageView.

There is Something about that process that I'm just not grokking, though.  The following is the code I tried to use to update the widget.  I get nothing drawn on the screen at all.  The ImageView has a placeholder image just set by its `src` property.  When I don't run the code to update it to my drawing, the placeholder image stays in place.  So, I know this code is doing *something*, just obviously not the *right* thing.

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(0, 360));
drawable.getPaint().setColor(0xffff0000);
drawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(5.0f);
drawable.setIntrinsicWidth(100);
drawable.setIntrinsicHeight(100);
drawable.draw(canvas);

views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ImageView01, bitmap);     
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

I knew it couldn't be that easy.  So, am I even heading in the right direction?

---

**Update**

Ok, maybe that was too much information.  The question I'm really trying to ask is this:

If I want to draw shapes on a widget, should I use an ImageView and create a bitmap from my ShapeDrawable or is there more appropriate way to draw into a widget where it is constrained by RemoteViews?

Comment: Are you saying that the placeholder is still there when trying to draw something over it?

Comment: No, the placeholder image goes away.  It ends up with nothing visual on the screen.  I can, however, hold-click on the widget and remove it still.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is actually a widget called [`AnalogClock`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AnalogClock.html) in the SDK that is very similar to what you are trying to do.

It is implemented as a class that extends `View` and is annotated with `@RemoteView`. It registers receivers on `Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK` and `Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` and draws itself by overriding the `onDraw` method. Check out the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/AnalogClock.java). The standard [AlarmClock](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/AlarmClock.git;a=summary) application [exposes](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/AlarmClock.git;a=blob_plain;f=AndroidManifest.xml;hb=HEAD) [this](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/AlarmClock.git;a=blob_plain;f=res/xml/analog_appwidget.xml;hb=HEAD) [view](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/AlarmClock.git;a=blob_plain;f=res/layout/analog_appwidget.xml;hb=HEAD) as a widget that can be added to the home screen.

I think that is a good (if not the best) way to implement what you described and obviously works well.

Comment: Oh, cool.  I was under the impression that you could not extend a view and add it to a RemoteView because only very specific types were allowed in a RemoteView, even subclasses.  If that's all it takes, then I guess I should be able to rock and roll.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: This is the documentation which gave me that impression:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

Comment: I did try it out and unfortunately you cannot subclass view and add it to a layout used in a RemoteView, as far as I can tell.  The only reason that it works for the AnalogClock view is that AnalogClock is one of those explicitly allowed components.

Comment: But do you know how to create custon View descedant using @RemoteView ? I tried to create own one, but widgets crashs on load.

Comment: Same here. I'm thinking it's only available to views in the sdk.

Comment: "[AnalogClock] class was deprecated in API level 23.
This widget is no longer supported." (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AnalogClock.html)

Answer (score 5):

This works great:

```
Paint p = new Paint(); 
p.setAntiAlias(true);
p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
p.setStrokeWidth(8);
p.setColor(0xFFFF0000);

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawArc(new RectF(10, 10, 90, 90), 0, 270, false, p);

RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(updateService.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.canvas, bitmap);

ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(updateService, DashboardAppWidgetProvider.class);
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(updateService);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, views);
```

I guess the problem with your original code was just the way of drawing the arc - that's why nothing showed up.

BTW: You can find a customizable "Arc Clock" with a very small memory footprint in the Market by searching for "arc clock"!

Answer (score 0):

To create an custom component, I would extend View or any subclass of View and override the onDraw(Canvas canvas) method to do your drawing. On the the canvas object you can call methods such as drawLine(), drawArc(), drawPicture(), drawPoints(), drawText(), drawRect(), etc.....

[Here's more details.](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

[Here's the api for canvas.](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)

I believe you can then add your custom view to a remote view for the purpose of making a widget.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the whole problem.  If I could just subclass a view, it would be really simple.  However, a RemoteViews which you use to talk to a widget can only contain a very specific set of elements.