# Dynamically change ImageButton background inside a homescreen widget

Tags: android, android-widget, selector

I'm working on an Android widget which essentially places a button on the homescreen. The button uses a `selector` in order to show a default state and a pressed state.  Each state has its own image, as you'll see in the code below.

I already have code to [change the hue of an image](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9e215c83c3819953) and return a new StateListDrawable for use in the ImageButton.

**My question**: How do I actually apply the StateListDrawable to the ImageButton's `android:background` attribute using the RemoteView?

Here is the XML source for the widget layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonselector" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Instead of using the hardcoded "@drawable/buttonselector" it needs to be the dynamic selector I'm generating.

Comment: I think it may involve creating a new StateListDrawable: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted an answer [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289388/accessing-layout-items-from-inside-widget-appwidgetprovider/4624734#4624734) which I think is similar to your problem. This, however, involves two layouts that are almost similar. The only difference is the part that should change.